# Pantheon DE set some applications to display with header bars instead of title bars

Tags: unity, pantheon

I recently installed the Pandtheon DE on my laptop, but now whenever I use unity, several applications have header bars instead of title bars. I don't like this, because it messes up how the window looks in fullscreen.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshots? That way it is easier for us to understand the problem.

Comment: okay here you go: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0QIuL9hktxZcWNXMU1FTDk4Sk0/view?usp=sharing

the terminal window is the one with the header I want to reset. the file manager is what it should look like